# How do you create a continuous loop for a Coin tossing game in Java?

Tags: java

I am having issues trying to make my code loop back and do the program over again until the user asks them to stop by inputting zero.  I have tried a while statement but I am not sure if I implemented it correctly since all I got back was errors.  I appreciate any and all the help that can be given.  I have included my code below.

```
public class CoinTossing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

//Scanner method
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice;

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Coin Toss Program.");

//Variables for the count of heads and tails.
        int headCount = 0;
        int tailCount = 0;

        System.out.println("How many coin flips do you want to do?");
        int number = input.nextInt();
        for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
            Random rand = new Random();

            // Simulate the coin tosses.
            for (int count = 0; count < number; count++) {

                if (rand.nextInt(2) == 0) {
                    tailCount++;
                } else {
                    headCount++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Times head was flipped:" + headCount);
            System.out.println("Times tail was flipped:" + tailCount);
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: *"I have tried a while statement but I am not sure if I implemented it correctly since all I got back was errors."* - The code shown contains no use of a `while` loop, nor are any errors specified in the description.  Can you update the question to include the code which demonstrates the problem as well as information about the problem you've observed?

Answer (score 0):

Your main method could look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Coin Toss Program.");

        //Variables for the count of heads and tails.
        
        while (true) {
            int headCount = 0;
            int tailCount = 0;

            System.out.println("How many coin flips do you want to do?");
            int number = input.nextInt();

            if (number == 0) { break; }

            Random rand = new Random();
            // Simulate the coin tosses.
            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
                if (rand.nextInt(2) == 0) {
                    tailCount++;
                } else {
                    headCount++;
                }
            }
            
            System.out.println("Times head was flipped:" + headCount);
            System.out.println("Times tail was flipped:" + tailCount);
        }
    }
```

Here, the while loop is entered after the welcome message and will only exit the simulation when the user inputs a 0.

After the user input is retrieved, it will check if the user input 0. If the user inputs 0, it will `break` the while loop before the program simulates flipping the coin:

```
if (number == 0) { break; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your code into a **while** loop with the exception of these two lines:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Welcome to the Coin Toss Program.");
```

At the end of the Coin Toss Game the natural order of things would be to ask the User if he/she wants to play again. This allows the User to quit the application rather than being stuck in a continuous loop:

```
String yn = "y";
while (yn.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
    int headCount = 0;
    int tailCount = 0;
    int number = 0;
    String num = null;
    while (num == null) {
        System.out.print("How many coin flips do you want to do? --> ");
        num = input.nextLine();
        if (!num.matches("\\d+")) {
            System.err.println("Invalid Integer Number Supplied (" 
                             + num + ")! Try Again...");
            System.out.println();
            num = null;
        }
    }
    number = Integer.valueOf(num);
    // Simulate the coin tosses.
    for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
        if (rand.nextInt(2) == 0) {
            tailCount++;
        }
        else {
            headCount++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Times head was flipped:" + headCount);
    System.out.println("Times tail was flipped:" + tailCount);

    System.out.println();
    while (yn.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
        System.out.print("Do you want to play again? (y/n) --> ");
        yn = input.nextLine();
        if (yn.matches("[yYnN]")) {
            System.out.println();
            break;
        }
        else {
            System.err.println("Invalid response (" + yn + ")! 'y' or 'n' only!");
            System.out.println();
            yn = "y";
        }
    }
}
```

The whole application may look something like this:

```
public class CoinTossing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        java.util.Random rand = new java.util.Random();
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Coin Toss Program");
        System.out.println("================================");
        System.out.println();

        String yn = "y";
        while (yn.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            int headCount = 0;
            int tailCount = 0;
            int number = 0;
            String num = null;
            while (num == null) {
                System.out.print("How many coin flips do you want to do? --> ");
                num = input.nextLine();
                if (!num.matches("\\d+")) {
                    System.err.println("Invalid Integer Number Supplied (" 
                                     + num + ")! Try Again...");
                    System.out.println();
                    num = null;
                }
            }
            number = Integer.valueOf(num);
            // Simulate the coin tosses.
            for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
                if (rand.nextInt(2) == 0) {
                    tailCount++;
                }
                else {
                    headCount++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Times head was flipped:" + headCount);
            System.out.println("Times tail was flipped:" + tailCount);

            System.out.println();
            while (yn.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                System.out.print("Do you want to play again? (y/n) --> ");
                yn = input.nextLine();
                if (yn.matches("[yYnN]")) {
                    System.out.println();
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    System.err.println("Invalid response (" + yn + ")! 'y' or 'n' only!");
                    System.out.println();
                    yn = "y";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```